# c++ cannot use same class as private base

Tags: c++, inheritance

I wonder why the following example does not compile:
I have an ImageContainer class, which inherits from Image privately (so that, it's users should not know that it inherits from Image).
This class also contains a list of images and has an AddImage function.

```
class ImageContainer: private Image {
public:
    ImageContainer (){};

    void addImage (const Image &img){
        //adds image to the container
    };

    std::vector<Image> images;
};

class DerivedImageContainer: public ImageContainer {
public:

    void init () {
        addImage (Image (background, Position(960, 533), Align::MiddleCenter));
    }
};
```

From a derived class (DerivedImageContainer) I want to call the addImage function, adding a new image to the list.

I was surprised to see that this does not compile. The error is:

```
error: ‘class Image Image::Image’ is inaccessible within this context
```

I am creating an Image that is absolutely not related to the ImageContainer's base class
And I am not even touching the ImageContaner's internal stuff, I am only calling a public function. Why does the compiler complain?

Does this mean, that in derived functions we cannot use members, that have the same type as private-inherited-class, somewhere in the class hierarchy?

It does not work with g++ 4.8.2 and g++ 7.5.0

Comment: Can you show the `Image` class declaration?

Comment: If you need to inherit from `Image` then you will need `public` inheritance. However, your code looks like `ImageContainer` *uses* the `Image` class (as a member, in the vector) but does *not* really need to actually inherit from it.

Comment: @AdrianMole There is no reason why one would _need_ public inheritance when inheriting.

Comment: Not related to your question: inheriting from `Image` seems wrong since a container and an image don't have the **is a** relationship i.e. a container of images is not an image

Answer (score 8):

Access checks are performed *after* name lookup. And the problem here is that of scope. Inside the scope of a class, unqualified name lookup proceeds from within it into its bases. And so it finds `Image` as the type name of a base. Then it must check the accessibility of this base. Hence the error.

The remedy is to not do unqualified name lookup. Specify `Image` by another way.

```
addImage ( ::Image (background, Position(960, 533), Align::MiddleCenter) );
```

`::Image` is the fully qualified name of the type at namespace scope. So it skips the lookup inside class scope.

Comment: Alternatively, add in the public scope of ImageContainter: `using Image = Image;`

Comment: Alternatively, just forget about private inheritance, or remove the private base of `ImageContainer` altogether. I mean, since when is an `ImageContainer` actually an `Image`? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: If anybody has an alternative answer to the question, I suggest they post it in the the answer box down yonder.